# A worthless little puzzle

Tags: password

A quick puzzle to pass the time.
Find the three word passphrase from the clues. You will know the answer when you see it.

Clues:

ale/ail/gale
conal/vane
Nero/sib
oiler/piper
rant/wallow

Comment: Please note that you must be a fluent English speaker to solve this riddle. I, like most non-natives, miss the highly specific vocabulary.

Comment: @Zsolt Yes, the same applies to many English language based puzzles/riddles on this site. Fortunately we non-native speakers can enjoy other parts of the site.

Comment: @WhatsUp: Not complaining about having riddles that I just can't solve. The frustrating part is that I don't know beforehand, so I spend hours in a futile attempt.

Comment: @Zsolt I also had the same experience, so I don't spend too much time on these riddles now, thinking that it's probably beyond my English level. Perhaps there can be some tag that specifically indicates that a puzzle requires high level of English (or any language) skill. This might be discussed in meta or the chat room.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Each of these is

> an anagram of a bird, minus its first letter.

Explanations:

> **T**eal/**R**ail/**E**agle; **F**alcon/**R**aven; **H**eron/**I**bis; **O**riole/**D**ipper; **B**rant/**S**wallow

So the passphrase is

> found by anagramming those first letters: it's **FOR THE BIRDS**!

Comment: Excellent work!

Comment: OMG, that's fast! +1